# git's equivalent of svnlook changed

Tags: git, svn

Is there a Git command equivalent to Subversion's:

```
svnlook changed -r REVISION REPO
```

I'm interested in the first character indicating whether a file has been Added, Deleted, or Updated. If there are ready-to-use scripts that would do this, it's fine. I know I can do this via script, parsing the output (like of git show hash --pretty=medium, look for 'new file mode', etc), I'm just wondering if there is something out there already so I don't need to reinvent the wheel. Otherwise I'll just do it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I finally found a way to accomplish this through git itself!

```
 git log --name-status --diff-filter=ACDMRT -U 3a94917b577fd0af90e013d9b3a7a36a211c2533
```

Nice! :)